# using window.location.href to pass variables in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make a page which when refreshed it passes a variable back to itself.

the npm package for the toasts(messages) I am using would not allow me to display these before the redirect as the redirect would happen to fast and erase the toast.

I solved this initially by saving these to localstorage but any fellow web dev would hiss at the sound of that.

so essentially.this is my code.

```
pageRelocator(mssg) {

    if (mssg.length < 35) {

        window.location.href = "http://localhost:3000/completed-assessment";
    } else if (mssg.length > 35) {


     this.setState({redoToken : "yes"})

        window.location.href = `http://localhost:3000/user-questions`;
    }
  }
```

Would I be able to pass a variable through one of these such as

```
 window.location.href = `http://localhost:3000/user-questions:${MY CUSTOM VARIABLE}`;
```

and if so how would i retrieve it?

I am using react router dom so was thinking about just setting a boolean for each one and putting something like this in the render

```
{this.state.redoToken === "yes" && <Redirect to={{pathname :"/user-questions",
state: {id: " "}}} />}
 {this.state.redoToken === "no" && <Redirect to="/completed-assessment" />}
```

but once again seems to hacky for my liking.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: alright how would i retrieve it ?

Comment: What happens when the length is exactly 35?

Comment: @Joseph why? makes little sense

Comment: So use a query string, that is typically how you pass variable on a url

Comment: how would I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

What version of `react-router` are you using? As of v5.1 you can use `useParams()` to get your url parameters.

Like so,

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'

const { slug } = useParams()
```

And your route for the page would have the path `/user-questions/:slug`